# Assigning function pointer to void pointer in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to use a C library from my C++ project.

The C library has a function like this that I'm supposed to pass callback functions into:

```
void c_function(int args, const void *func){};
```

So my C++ code should call it like this:

```
int function1(int a) {return a;}
int function2(int a, int b) {return a+b;}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    c_function(1, function1);
    c_function(2, function2);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that if I compile this calling code as C, it works fine and doesn't even have any warnings. If I compile the calling code as C++, however, it has the compile error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)(int)' to 'const void*', for example.

I'm not sure what I need to do to get it working in C++. I'm going to have a lot of these calls in my C++ program.

My question is: how can I make this work without changing the calling code, and why does this work in C but not C++? I thought C++ was a superset of C.

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? I tried to put a lot of effort into simplifying my code and explaining my question clearly.

Comment: Visual Studio 2005 and 2010 don't report errors. I though void * was compatible with just about any pointer.

Comment: But this is actually a well written question. Simplified to the max, and yet very understandable. +1

Comment: @rcgldr Of course it isn't. Function and object pointers are separated.

Comment: @JakeL I don't know how you're compiling your code, since you didn't show it, but, casting between function and object pointers is not defined in C as it isn't in C++.

Comment: @JakeL - Perhaps changing the prototype to something like extern "C" c_function(int, int( * )(...));  or extern "C" c_function(int, int( * )(int, ...)); might work, where the (...) is used to deal with variable number of arguments.